# Windows XP SP3 cmd console freezes on exit command when in fullscreen mode

Tags: console, fullscreen, windows-xp

When I do Alt+F4 on pure clean cmd console in fullscreen mode it does exit out of the console process (a disk is working for split a second) but it fails to close the console window after that, so I have  frozen computer. The operating system seems to run normally under that, but I cannot do anything on the computer then since all I got on screen is a dead console, it doesn't react to any key combinations, only thing that I can do then is just hard restart by holding power button several seconds.

Have you any idea what's going on ? This is on my laptop and I never used full screen console before here so I don't know what I might done to have this. I have run some 'optimization' reg's and cmd's here to disable some services, but now I don't know which setting might it be.

edit: originally I wrote that the system was sp2, it is actually sp3

edit2: It behaves strangely on entering full screen too. For some seconds I'm presented with black screen, it looks like frozen, but after a while content do show. But on end if I forget to go out of full screen before exit I got situation of no return.

Comment: well firstly you should install SP3 ;)

Comment: sorry I've mistakenly wrote that system was sp2, it is sp3

Comment: that's alright :)

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> is not how to exit a Command Prompt, full screen or otherwise.

Instead, type `exit` and it should quit!

However, from re-reading your question, it looks like you may have bigger/unrelated issues. I am not sure the exact cause, but, I would try an upgrade of your graphics drivers as the first thing (as I previously have seen some issues that seem a little familiar).

Comment: Yup sounds like a graphics driver thing.  what other adj. stuff exists in a command prompt? There is all the buffer and window settings items, I cannot see any of the Command prompt settings effect that, but it would be eay enough to change them.    RSK82 would you have any other graphic slowdowns or feelings beyond that one full screen item? Have you Tested any full screen games lately? Specifically Full screen (make thier own screen) not full window.